# Why is the code misbehaving with tabs?

Tags: java

```
char[] array = {'h','e','l','l','o','h','i','e',' '};
System.out.println(array+"\t"+array.length);//FIX THIS
```

It prints :

```
[C@15db9742     9
```

But if I change the code to :

```
char[] array = {'h','e','l','l','o','h','i','e',' '};
System.out.println(array);//FIX THIS
```

It prints :

```
hellohie
```

Why can't I put a tab and a number in concatenation? Because the following code worked fine:

```
String array1 =  new String(array);
System.out.println(array1+'\t'+array1.length());
```

Comment: If you put a tab in it, as a String, you convert the char array to a String array.

Comment: `System.out.println(new String(array) + "\t" + array.length);` would work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

It has multiple `println` methods, when you try to `System.out.println(array)` it inokves the one with `char` array as the argument, that's why it prints nicely. When you try to invoke your different version, it doesn't know what you expect it to do with that array, that's why it doesn't print nicely. Tab has nothing to do with that.

You can, for example, do `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)+"\t"+whatever)`, or convert it to String before like you did, or a lot of other solutions.